# how can i put image link in json file on nuxtjs?

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxtjs

I'm using nuxtjs and I have a `data.json` file in my root directory and I want to add image link in this JSON file, but it does not know it
t
here my code:

```
{
  "id": 1,
    "cardImg": "./assets/images/image_1.jpg",
    "iconImg": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "subjectCard": "back-end"
},
```

[directory structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTWyB.png)

Comment: there is a typo on iconImg, there is an extra closing parenthesis at the end `)`

Comment: @djiss  thanks, I edited, but  the reason for the problem is not it

Comment: try `:src="require(`@/assets/images/${item.cardImg}`)"`, inside require use this ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way a few days ago :

here are the codes of `json` file:

```
 {
 "id": 1, "cardImg": "/image_1.jpg", "iconImg": "/icon.png", 
  "subjectCard":"back-end" 
 }
```

and here the codes for img tag:

```
:src="require(`../assets/images${item.cardImg}`)
```